# How to open this ZIF connector?

Tags: keyboard, connector

How do I open this ZIF connector of my HP laptop I tried applying force in various directions but all in vain. 
Here is the pic of it !

[image]

If you can show by drawing some arrows using MS paint it will be helpful thanks

Comment: Have you tried to lift up the white plastic? From the image it looks like you forced the ribbon cable without lifting the white plastic. What's your laptop model?

Comment: No I didn't try lifting the white plastic and some laptop guy fixed this ribbon and he is not available now. I have HP pavilion 15-n003tx

Comment: I am afraid because on YouTube they say this connector is so sensitive

Comment: Well.. when opening a laptop always search first on YouTube for a disassembly video. Even though you don't find your exact laptop model you can find something similar. It's so easy when you know what to do. I found this on YT: https://youtu.be/UwccwebeTYM?t=3m29s . Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Yes it helped, great :)

Answer (score 1):

The connector looks like it will flip up.  Exercise extreme caution.

With tiny parts like these, [a black stick or spudger](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4SR1PN4591&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Telephony%20Accessories-_-9SIA4SR1PN4591&gclid=CJK8v6zh5NACFca6wAodL4QD4w&gclsrc=aw.ds) is very helpful.  Connectors like these are common on cell phones and also common on laptops now.

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for this one for a while
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njVey0vOm1k
Unlike a lot of other models, this one has a lever on the BLACK hinge. The white is connected to the base.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.